# Automatically execute statements in sbt console

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to define a bunch of statements that should be executed once the `sbt console` is up and running in `build.sbt` (e.g. imports or basic 'mock' data to test code on)?

I'm finding myself typing the same basic setup statements every time I fire up the sbt console and it would be neat if I could define these statements as 'auto-run'.

Comment: A workaround is to put your basic setup statements in a Scala file and load it using `:load` in console.